# Crystal does not doing auto infer type for union?

Tags: crystal-lang

When I use a type union in Crystal with `String` and `Int32`, and then I assigned a value to it , it works fine

```
test : (String | Int32) = 100
puts "Hello, World! #{test}"
```

Resulting

```
~/Projects/learn-crystal  crystal hello.cr
Hello, World! 100
```

---

But, when I change the `Int32` to `UInt32`, it will become an error

```
test : (String | UInt32) = 100
puts "Hello, World! #{test}"
```

Resulting

```
~/Projects/learn-crystal  crystal hello.cr
Showing last frame. Use --error-trace for full trace.

In hello.cr:1:1

 1 | test : (String | UInt32) = 100
     ^---
Error: type must be (String | UInt32), not Int32
```

---

But this works fine though

```
test : (String | UInt32) = 100_u32
puts "Hello, World! #{test}"
```

Resulting

```
~/Projects/learn-crystal  crystal hello.cr
Hello, World! 100
```

Why Crystal does not doing auto infer for an union of one integer and string type?

Comment: This is a valid enhancement. Please open an issue! Thank you!

Comment: https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/issues/8474 was created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been fixed since v0.36.0.

https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/issues/8474